# Junit Parameterized tests together with Powermock by PowerMockRunnerDelegate doesn't work

Tags: java, junit, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to use PowerMock (v. 1.6.5) together with Parametrized test (Junit v.4.11). I use Java 1.8.0_91. I would like to use PowerMockRunnerDelegate annotations but it doesn't work as it should.
Here you have code:

```
package com.orange.probe.measureCapability;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;

import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(value = Parameterized.class)
public class ParametrizedTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public int expected;

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<?> getValues() {
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4},
                {5},
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testParametrized() {
        System.out.println(expected);
    }
}
```

I should receive output like below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But I receive output like this:

```
0
```

It works well with annotation @RunWith(Parameterized.class). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's rather some environment issue. I just copied your code and it works fine. The output is correct. What versions on JUnit and PawerMock do you use?

Comment: Same here, copy-paste works just as @SergheyBishyr said. On an _off-topic note_, depending on your company's restrictions you can take a look at the [Zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) (LGPL) a/o [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) (Apache 2) libraries, which offer a more elegant way to define data sets for your tests.